# Number to Text converter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, numbers-to-words

I've written this code in Haskell to convert a number into its written form. It feels ok but at the same time I feel like it can probably be improved on a lot. I would appreciate help in improving it.

```
nums :: Int -> String
nums x = case x of
    0 -> "zero"
    1 -> "one"
    2 -> "two"
    3 -> "three"
    4 -> "four"
    5 -> "five"
    6 -> "six"
    7 -> "seven"
    8 -> "eight"
    9 -> "nine"
    10 -> "ten"
    11 -> "eleven"
    12 -> "twelve"
    13 -> "thirteen"
    14 -> "fourteen"
    15 -> "fifteen"
    16 -> "sixteen"
    17 -> "seventeen"
    18 -> "eighteen"
    19 -> "nineteen"
    20 -> "twenty"
    30 -> "thirty"
    40 -> "forty"
    50 -> "fifty"
    60 -> "sixty"
    70 -> "seventy"
    80 -> "eighty"
    90 -> "ninety"
    100 -> "hundred"
    _ -> ""

bigNums :: Int -> String
bigNums x =
    case x of
        1 -> "thousand"
        2 -> "million"
        3 -> "billion"
        4 -> "trillion"
        5 -> "quadrillion"
        6 -> "quintillion"
        7 -> "sextillion"
        8 -> "septillion"
        9 -> "octillion"
        10 -> "nonillion"

isEmpty :: String -> Bool
isEmpty "" = True
isEmpty s = False

numToEnglish :: String -> Int -> String
numToEnglish start num
    | len > 3 =
        let exponent = ((len-1) `div` 3) * 3
            powerNum = bigNums (exponent `div` 3)
        in
            if powerNum == ""
                then ""
            else
                let numHead = read $ take (len-exponent) stringNum
                    numTail = read $ drop (len-exponent) stringNum
                    numStart = numToEnglish "" numHead ++ " " ++ powerNum
                in startSpace ++ numToEnglish numStart numTail
    | len == 3 = numToEnglish (startSpace ++ nums firstNum ++ " " ++ nums 100) intTail
    | len == 2 =
        let tens = nums (firstNum * 10)
            includeDash = if not $ isEmpty tens then "-" else ""
        in
        if firstNum == 1 
            then startSpace ++ nums num
        else
            if intTail == 0
                then startSpace ++ tens
            else startSpace ++ tens ++ includeDash ++ nums intTail
    | len == 1 =
        if start == ""
            then numHead
        else if firstNum == 0
            then start
        else start ++ " " ++ numHead
    | otherwise = ""
    where
        stringNum = show num
        len = length stringNum
        firstNum = read [head stringNum] :: Int
        numHead = if firstNum > 1 || isEmpty start then nums firstNum else ""
        intTail = read (drop 1 stringNum) :: Int
        startSpace = if isEmpty start then start else start ++ " "


convert :: Int -> String
convert = numToEnglish ""
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the primary issue with your current implementation is that it's attempting to do math on strings. For example,

```hs
let numHead = read $ take (len-exponent) stringNum
    numTail = read $ drop (len-exponent) stringNum
```

can be expressed with a much simpler `divMod` usage. Replacing your numeric strings with numbers will probably lead you to a much simpler and cleaner implementation right out of the gate. Much of your code can remain similar, but `numToEnglish` would likely be drastically simplified.

Another specific point I would suggest addressing is that `nums` currently has an unclear responsibility. It does not always convert the number to an English string, and this makes it somewhat harder to understand its usage. I recommend breaking more responsibility into these smaller functions, and having one function do all the work to convert numbers < 100. My implementation (below) also creates another function to deal with multiples of ten, which are mixed together with numbers < 20 in your implementation.

While you certainly could use a function `Int -> String` for the order of magnitude (what you called `bigNums`) you can see in my implementation that I think using a list produces a nicer solution, especially if you break the number into parts for each order of magnitude first (as I did).

More minor nitpicks:

You explicitly annotated your functions as taking `Int`s. The maximum value this algorithm could apply to does not fit into an `Int`, whose maximum value is about 2^63, or a bit over 9 quintillion. I would suggest using `Integral a => a -> String` so numbers as large as 999 nonillion can actually be passed to `convert`.

Your `isEmpty` function is equivalent to `null`, from the prelude.

If any invalid inputs are given, your functions will produce non-exhaustive pattern errors or fail silently. The former may be a matter of style, but `convert` should probably fail quickly if it does not know how to convert the provided number.

Here's my implementation, feel free to let me know if you have any questions:

```hs
import Data.List (unfoldr, intercalate)
import Data.Tuple (swap)

-- Convert an integer in [0, 100) to an English number.
-- Example:
-- `convertSmall 64 == "sixty-four"`
convertSmall :: Integral a => a -> String
convertSmall x = case x of
    0 -> ""
    1 -> "one"
    2 -> "two"
    3 -> "three"
    4 -> "four"
    5 -> "five"
    6 -> "six"
    7 -> "seven"
    8 -> "eight"
    9 -> "nine"
    10 -> "ten"
    11 -> "eleven"
    12 -> "twelve"
    13 -> "thirteen"
    14 -> "fourteen"
    15 -> "fifteen"
    16 -> "sixteen"
    17 -> "seventeen"
    18 -> "eighteen"
    19 -> "nineteen"
    x | x < 100 && x >= 20 -> case x `divMod` 10 of
        (tens, 0) -> convertTens (tens * 10)
        (tens, ones) -> convertTens (tens * 10) ++ "-" ++ convertSmall ones
    _ -> error "convertSmall can only be applied to integers in [0, 100)"

-- Converts a multiple of ten in [20, 90] to an English number.
-- Example:
-- `convertTens 30 == "thirty"`
convertTens :: Integral a => a -> String
convertTens x = case x of
    20 -> "twenty"
    30 -> "thirty"
    40 -> "forty"
    50 -> "fifty"
    60 -> "sixty"
    70 -> "seventy"
    80 -> "eighty"
    90 -> "ninety"
    _ -> error "convertTens can only be applied to multiples of 10 in [20, 90]"

-- Converts a number in [0, 1000) to an English number.
-- Example:
-- `convertHundreds 289 == "two hundred eighty-nine"`
convertHundreds :: Integral a => a -> String
convertHundreds x | x >= 0 && x < 1000 = case x `divMod` 100 of
    (0, 0) -> ""
    (0, rest) -> convertSmall rest
    (hundreds, 0) -> convertSmall hundreds ++ " hundred"
    (hundreds, rest) -> convertSmall hundreds ++ " hundred " ++ convertSmall rest
convertHundreds _ = error "convertHundreds can only be applied to integers in [0, 1000)"

-- The names of orders of magnitude
orders :: [String]
orders =
    [ ""
    , " thousand"
    , " million"
    , " billion"
    , " trillion"
    , " quadrillion"
    , " quintillion"
    , " sextillion"
    , " septillion"
    , " octillion"
    , " nonillion"
    ]

-- Get the parts of each order of magnitude.
-- Example:
-- `orderParts 1391290 == [290, 391, 13]
orderParts :: Integral a => a -> [a]
orderParts x = unfoldr getParts x
    where
        getParts :: Integral a => a -> Maybe (a, a)
        getParts 0 = Nothing
        getParts x = Just $ swap $ x `divMod` 1000

-- Convert a number and an order into an English number.
-- Example:
-- `convertOrder " million" 734 == "seven hundred thirty-four million"`
convertOrder :: Integral a => String -> a -> String
convertOrder _ 0 = ""
convertOrder orderName x = convertHundreds x ++ orderName

-- Convert a number into an English number.
-- Example:
-- `convert 782301 == "seven hundred eighty-two thousand three hundred one"`
convert :: Integral a => a -> String
convert 0 = "zero"
convert x | (fromIntegral x :: Integer) < 10 ^ 33
    = intercalate " "
    $ reverse
    $ filter (not . null)
    $ zipWith convertOrder orders
    $ orderParts x
convert _ = error "convert can only be applied to integers in [0, 10^33)"
```